# Why can’t I access a property on “this” in a class via its prototype?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, prototype, es6-class

I wrote this class and have set up an array property for it. Then, I want to add an item to this array.

However, when I try to do it, I get the error “Uncaught `TypeError`: Cannot read property `push` of `undefined`”.

Isn’t this possible?

```js
class test {
  constructor() {
    this.myArray = [];
  }

  myMethod() {
    this.myArray.push("ok");
  }
};

console.log(test.prototype.myMethod());
```

Comment: This won't help with your question, but by convention you should be capitalizing "test" (`class Test {}`) in constructor functions/classes. Just a little helpful tidbit.

Answer (score 5):

That’s not how classes are used. You need to instantiate `test` first, by using `new test()`. The `constructor` was never called in your case, so `this.myArray` was never defined.

This is the only way this can work:

```
let testInstance = new test();

testInstance.myMethod();
```

This way, the `constructor` is called and there will be no error.

Of course, next you’ll need some way of retrieving your array, in order to see the effect.

Answer (score 1):

try to create the instance first. See the code I've commented it in details

```
test.prototype = { 
  constructor: test,
  myMethod: function() {
    this.myArray.push("ok");
  }
};
```

```js
var test = function(){
  this.myArray = [];
}
test.prototype = { // add our custom constructor and custom methods
  constructor: test,
  myMethod: function() {
    this.myArray.push("ok");
  }
};

var myVar = new test(); // create new instance of test
myVar.myMethod(); // run custom method to push val
console.log( myVar.myArray );
```

Comment: Curious why you decided to go the constructor function route with your answer?

Answer (score 1):

You need to initiate your class test first.

```
var t = new test();
```

For your information:

```
console.log(test.prototype.myMethod());
```

will give you "undefined". Try e.g. :

```
var t = new test();
t.myMethod();
console.log(t.myArray);
```

to get output similar to this:

```
Array [ "ok" ]
```